# Dynamic addition of multiple records in an one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model "Contact" with 3 variables: `category`, `name` and `phone`.

At the one page I have a form with the same text fields. A `category` text field could be filled only once but the `name` and `phone` fields could be added (with jQuery) as much as needed.

As a result I want several records in the database from **one query** (one page) where a `category` will be same for each record but the `name` and `phone` fields related to the query.

**My question is** how to able create such form?

I've found info about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but as I understood it's necessary for the linked addition between two models.

Also, I found info that complex form could be make with such code:

**Controller.rb**

```
def task_attributes=(task_attributes)
  task_attributes.each do |attributes|
    tasks.build(attributes)
  end
end
```

**Helper.rb**

```
def new
   @contact = Project.new
   10.times { @contact.tasks.build }
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
...
<% fields_for "contact[task_attributes][]", task do |task_form| %>
...
```

But in that case I should know how many fields `name` and `phone` will be there but I don't know it because I want make able to add it dynamically on the page with JavaScript (jQuery).

Comment: See http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and there is a revised one too.

Comment: I saw this video but I don't completely got the idea of the nested form. I mean that I understood it like I described it in the question: there should be some model, for instance, a contact and some model with fields, for instance, contact_fields. After that I should have: **contact** `has_many :contact_fields` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_fields`, right?